# How to show curve vertex tilt + radius value slider in custom toolshelf panel

Tags: python, interface

Is it possible to generate a field in the a custom toolshelf panel that displays the curve vertex tilt value and make it editable like the tilt slider insider the transform tab in the properties panel?

I see that the operator is `transform.tilt` but I have no idea how to generate a UI value slider that displays the value and can edit it.

Is that even possible with Blender?

[image]

Curve vertex tilt transform command:

```
bpy.ops.transform.tilt(value=8.36929, mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=0.0323492)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the content of that Transform panel are defined outside of the Python api. But you could have something monsterously convoluted like this to show up the Tilt value of a single selected Control Point of a bezier_point

```
    if context.active_object:
        if not context.active_object.data:
            pass
        else:
            # you do more checking here to verify the kind of active_object 
            # I will ommit this from the example. 

            data = context.active_object.data
            points = data.splines.active.bezier_points

            selected_points = [idx for idx, p in enumerate(points) if p.select_control_point]
            print(selected_points)
            if len(selected_points) == 1:
                idx = selected_points[0]
                point = points[idx]
                col = layout.column()
                col.prop(point, "weight_softbody", text='weight')
                col.prop(point, "radius", text='radius')
                col.prop(point, "tilt", text='tilt')
```

This approach only works when 1 point is selected, i'm sure it's possible to adjust the mean value too but it's more complicated, and might involve writing your own operator -- I haven't looked very deeply.

Comment: thats too bad that this part of Blender is not so easily accessible via Python. Thank you for looking into it.